# How to edit the label of a chart in Excel?

Tags: excel, charts

As shown in the figure below, the horizontal axis is automatically produced by the Excel and labeled as 1,2,...,n. What I wanna to do is to change these labels into such a form as case A, case B,..., etc.

I tried to edit the chart, but all failed.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways you can set the x-axis category labels for the chart.

**One way** is to put your labels into a range on your worksheet and then include them in the data source for your chart. This is usually done when you create the chart. If the labels are entered in the row above the chart data, Excel will recognize them as x-axis labels. The graphic below shows an example of the setup.

[image]

Then you would select the entire range with both labels & data--cells C8:E11--in this case, and insert your chart, with results as shown. This method works with all versions of Excel.

[image]

**The second way** involves editing the chart's settings after it has been created. Step-by-step, here's what's involved (This may work in older versions, but I did it in Excel 2010).

1. Select your chart and then pick the Chart Tools/Design options on the ribbon.
2. Then choose Select Data from the options (still on the ribbon).
3. The chart data range is shown at the top of the dialog box that comes up, with a box below left to make changes to the chart settings for the data series and a box at below right to make changes to the x-axis labels. The latter box will list the "1", "2", etc. numbers that you want to change.
4. Hit the edit button for the right-hand box (Horizontal Category (Axis) Labels), and you will be prompted to enter an axis label range.
5. Instead of selecting a range, though, just enter the labels that you want to see on the x-axis, separated by commas, like so:

[image]

6. Press OK, and then again when the Select Data Source dialogue reappears, and it's done.

[image]

Comment: Excellent!!! I used the second way and it indeed works！Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation. BTW, I think MS should improve this part to make it much more intuitive to edit.

Answer (score -1):

I assume your chart is backed by data in 1 or more other worksheets?

Go to those worksheets and determine what part of the data generates the x-axis.  Make changes (or additions) there and it should be reflected immediately in the chart.

More explanation of your problem would be helpful.

Comment: As I said, the horizontal axis is automatically generated by Excel. I didn't make any special label over the original data. I was wondering where to modify.